# Problemas com o bake no CakePHP 3.x "Your database does not have any tables."

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-3

Saudações!
Estou tentando gerar os models, controllers e templates em um projeto com CakePHP 3.x usando o banco de dados PostgreSQL. 
Já criei as tabelas, configurei a conexão (que está funcionando, segundo a página inicial default do Cake), mas quando executo o bake, recebo o seguinte retorno:

```
bin/cake bake all

Welcome to CakePHP v3.4.3 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /home/leandro/sites/taskmanager/src/
PHP : 7.0.15-1ubuntu4
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake All
---------------------------------------------------------------
Possible model names based on your database:
Your database does not have any tables.
```

O pacote php7.0-pgsql já está instalado e a conexão via navegador está correta, mas o bake não passa desse ponto e não consigo gerar os arquivos. O que fazer? Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Será que seu banco não tem um esquema diferente do default. Se sim, precisa indicar isso no config/app.php:

'schema' => 'nome_esquema',

Answer (score 0):

Um outro motivo desta mensagem é quando você não dá os devidos privilégios para o usuário nas tabelas.

Se for para que o usuário us_testes tenha permissão total no esquema sc_testes use:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA sc_testes TO us_testes;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA sc_testes TO us_testes;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA sc_testes TO us_testes;
```